# How to wait data from fetching json file and then continue

Tags: javascript, api

I am new in JavaScript and I have a problem:

I do `fetch('path')`, then I assign values and return it. Later I call this function in my other functions but it runs first with empty values without waiting values to be assigned. How can I solve this? I think I should use `async` and `await` but do not know exactly how.

```
function loadLocalJson(path) {
let users = [];

fetch(path)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok :(');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(results => {
        users = results
        console.log(users);
    }) 
    .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));

return users;
}

function getFilteredAndSortedArray(users, price) {
    console.log(users, price);
    return users.filter(user => {
        return user.salary && user.salary > price;
    })
    .sort(user => user.name);
}

users = loadLocalJson('users.json');
usersB= getFilteredAndSortedArray(users, 1000);
console.log(usersB, usersA);

// PrefixedUsersArray(users)    
// ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how asynchronous code works. A fetch request returns a promise, so you must return the promise and access the value using `.then()`:

```
function loadLocalJson(path) {
  return fetch(path)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok :(');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error', err))
}

function getFilteredAndSortedArray(users, price) {
  console.log(users, price);
  return users.filter(user => {
    return user.salary && user.salary > price;
  }).sort(user => user.name);
}

loadLocalJson('users.json').then(users => {
  usersB = getFilteredAndSortedArray(users, 1000);
  console.log(usersB, users);
})
```

You do not have to assign users, you can just return the promise, sinc eyou have already called `response.json()`. Also, your sort function most likely won't work, try something like this:

```
users.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

Comment: So it is better to make that loadLocalJson() returns a json promise(response.json) and then I do things with `then()`, instead of doing something with async and await to get assigned values?

Comment: That is entirely down to preference on which you use, I feel `.then` is easier to read and is more verbose. It is a lot less hassle too, since you don't have to mark every function as async

Comment: but after that my all related users code should be put in `.then()` ?

Comment: As long as you are using the value, then yes. You could use `async / await` in the main thread if you wanted to.